# Como detectar internet lenta?

Tags: android, xamarin

Existe alguma maneira minimamente confiável de detectar que o usuário está em uma conexão lenta?

Basicamente, em meu aplicativo, gostaria de detectar tal condição e omitir o carregamento de algumas informações complementares de um WebService.

Então, é possível detectar uma conexão lenta, porém funcional, de internet?